# How to retreive data from url using SLUG php mysql

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, slug

I just want to send slug of the blog in href. Code post_url = slug of that blog title

```
<h3><a href="<?= $base_url ?>blog/<?=$rowposts['post_url']?>">Read</a></h3>
```

Url will be this - http://localhost/Office/VTPL/Varneli%20HOME_CMS/vareli-home/blog/this-is-my-blog

[image]

Here is the .htaccess file screenshot. Please check the selected line

[image]

Please help me out... How will I do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your .htaccess line with this

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$    blog/blog-details.php?post=$1     [L,QSA]
```

To get URL, PHP code

```
$full_url = "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
```